# Unhandled promise rejection while trying to set up a react-native tuner

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I'm currently developing an app which has to get real-time information about the current pitch.
Since I already build a website with the same function, I'm am using react-native with expo.

For pitch detection I use the following libary:
https://github.com/qiuxiang/react-native-tuner
which is build ontop of https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-recording.

Unfortunatly after calling Recording.init() inside the tuner class I get following error

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined]
```

The code in this class looks like this:

```
import Recording from "react-native-recording";
import PitchFinder from "pitchfinder";

export default class Tuner {
 ...

  constructor(sampleRate = 22050, bufferSize = 2048) {
    this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
    this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
    this.pitchFinder = new PitchFinder.YIN({ sampleRate: this.sampleRate });
  }

  start() {
    Recording.init({
      sampleRate: this.sampleRate,
      bufferSize: this.bufferSize,
    });
...
```

The tuner class is initialized here, so I should have permission to access the microphone after the prompt on the device:

```
...
async componentDidMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
      ]);
    }

    const tuner = new Tuner();
...
```

I have no idea on how to fix that since this is my first react-native app. Would gladly appreciate any help!

Comment: You are trying to start the app on iOS? Did you install pods after installing the `react-native-recording` library? `npx pod-install` or `cd ios && pod install`

Comment: No currently I'm just trying to get it up and running for android

Answer (score 0):

I figured that react-native libarys are not compatible with expo. Changed my project to a react-native one and it worked just fine.